# cmake shared lib with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, shared

I created two default projects with QtCreator v6.0.1: MyApp and MyLib for Linux(Ubuntu).
I changed the folders structure to

```
MyApp
├──build
│   ├──Debug
|   └──Release
├──src
├──libs
|   └──MyLib
|        ├──build
|        ├──src
|        ├──include
|        └──CMakeLists.txt
├──include
├──src
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

What kind of changes I need to make with both of CMakeLists.txt to make MyLib as shared library and use it in MyApp?

Comment: You probably need to add a `add_subdirectory` command in CMakeLists.txt of MyApp before creating the executable. After this command, you should link your built library include and lib folder path.

Comment: How to link built library include and lib folder path?

Comment: Use `target_include_directory` and `target_link_libraries` for that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as already mentioned, you'll need to add the `MyLib` directory with `add_subdirectory` in the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
    ...
    add_subdirectory(libs/MyLib)
    ...
```

Then, defining a shared/dynamic library with CMake is pretty straight forward. You use `add_library` providing the name of the library, the source files and some flags. By default it will create a static library, but with the keyword `SHARED` you can change that:

```
    add_library(MyLib SHARED
                MySource1.cpp
                MySource2.cpp
                ...
                )
```

Have a look here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

By the way, all generated code (including the library) will end up in the one and only build directory (which you either specify with `cmake -B $BUILD_DIR` or which is the working directory for running cmake). So you won't have an additional one in your libs/MyLib folder.

Comment: Thanks, after qmake approach it was hard to understand )